# Использование Ajax множество раз

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть около 10 всяких различных методов которые используют Аякс, и они продолжают расти. Для каждого метода я пишу:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            ......
        }, error: function(request, error, status) {
            .......
        }
    });
```

Сделал функцию getAjax(url, params) в которую передаю данные для отправки. Сам вопрос: как мне из аякс вернуть object **data** для дальнейшей работы с ним извне? Что бы не писать сам запрос аякс по 20 раз. Имеется ввиду дальнейшая работа с: `data.success`, `data.id`, `data.name` и т.д. вне самого аякс-запроса.

Comment: премного благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно передать обработчик ответа в функцию:

```js
// этот url для примера, он возвращает маленький json, 
// его запросим несколько раз, но это могли бы быть и разные url 
let url = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/64f72be3625c31003a460573a347aa4823ef8b1a62d0e768921972fe6880809d';

getSettings(function(settings) {
  // вот тут получены все настройки
  console.log(settings)
});

function getSettings(callback) {

  // объект, в который сохраняются результаты нескольких запросов
  let settings = {};
  
  // тут могли бы быть и разные Url
  getAjax(url, save('key1'));
  getAjax(url, save('key2'));
  getAjax(url, save('key3'));
  getAjax(url, save('key4'));
  getAjax(url, save('key5'));
  
  function save(key) {

    // функция, которая будет вызвана, когда отработает getAjax
    return function(data) {
 
      // сохраняем полученные данные в объект settings 
      settings[key] = data;

      // колбек будет вызван только когда в объекте settings образуется 5 ключей
      if(Object.keys(settings).length === 5)
        callback(settings)
    }
  }
}

function getAjax(url, func){
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      success: func, 
      error: function(request, error, status) {
          console.log(error)
      }
  }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

я не усложнял код выше умышленно, чтобы легче было разглядеть суть, но, но не отработает если хотя бы один из запросов провалится, нужно обработать это отдельно

---

Так же рекомендую присмотреться к [`fetсh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), это хоть и новое api но работает уже почти везде

```js
let url = 'https://www.jsonstore.io/64f72be3625c31003a460573a347aa4823ef8b1a62d0e768921972fe6880809d';

fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(d => console.log(d))
```

Comment: Но как связать  функцию getAjax с моими методами? Или спрошу даже так: Как управлять функцией getAjax внутри моих методов в которых я пишу основную логику в зависимости от полученного результата?

Comment: У меня есть метод, например `getSettings(){....}` внутри него я хочу выполнить `getAjax() {...}` и в зависимости о того что придёт от getAjax я хочу обработать данные в `getSettings(){....}`

Comment: Ну если у меня грубо сказать десять таких getSettings(){....},getSettings2(){....}....как то объёмно получается писать для каждого метода аякс запрос

Comment: как мне получить доступ теперь к данным `success`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94797/discussion-between-sergei1094-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте fetch или промисифицируйте $.ajax:

```js
function ajax(url, params, options = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax(Object.assign({
      type: "GET",
      url,
      data: params,
    }, options))
      .done(resolve)
      .fail(reject);
  });
}

let url = 'https://httpbin.org/get';
// Можно использовать все преимущества промисов:
Promise.all([
  ajax(url, {id: 1}),
  ajax(url, {id: 2}),
  ajax(url, {id: 3}),
  ajax(url, {id: 4}, {cache: false}), // можно добавлять доп. параметры
]).then(results => console.log(results)) // выводим все результаты
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

На JS я делал так:

```
function ajaxGET(url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      var status = request.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(request.responseText);
      }
    }
  };

  request.open("GET", url);
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  request.send();
}
```

callback - функция для возврата.

Пример вызова:

```
  ajaxGET(get_img_url, function(data) {
    changeSlide(data, id);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте перейдем в [документацию](https://api.jquery.com/JQuery.ajax/), выберем один из примеров, и постепенно изменяя и наращивая функционал, добьёмся желаемого поведения.

```
// Отправляем данные на сервер.
var request = $.ajax({
  // ... код.
});

// Уведомляем пользователя, как только запрос будет завершен.
// Альтернатива создания обработчика `success`.
request.done(function(response) {
  // ... код.
});

// Если запрос не удался, предупреждаем пользователя.
// Альтернатива создания обработчика `error`.
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  // ... код.
});
```

При этом обратите внимание, что запрос будет выполнен единожды, не зависимо от того сколько раз впоследствии будет выполнен метод `request.done(...)`, например:

```js
var request = $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/88');

request.fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
  alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
});

request.done(function(response, status, jqXHR) {
  $('#header').text(response.title);
});

request.done(function(response, status, jqXHR) {
  $('#body').text(response.body);
});
```

```html
<h3 id="header"></h3>
<p id="body"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

На данном этапе возникает **проблема 1**: постоянное формирование тела `$.ajax` метода. Создадим подобие вашей функции `getAjax(url, params)`.

```js
function get(resource, params = {}) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: resource,
    data: params,
    cache: false,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        alert('Рage not found.');
      }
    }
  });
}

var request = get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/88');

request.fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
  alert('Request failed: ' + status);
});

request.done(function(response, status, jqXHR) {
  $('#header').text(response.title);
  $('#body').text(response.body);
});
```

```html
<h3 id="header"></h3>
<p id="body"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Проблема 2**: постоянные обертки `done...done...fail` от [промиса](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Добавим "сахару" в виде `async/await`, плюс обработку ошибок через `try...catch`.

```js
function get(resource, params = {}) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: resource,
    data: params,
    cache: false,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        alert('Page not found.');
      }
    }
  });
}

function renderList(articles) {
  $.each(articles, function(index, article) {
    $("#results").append(`<li>${article.title}</li>`);
  });
}

// Пометили функцию как асинхронную `async`,
// заменили `.done` на заявление `await`.
async function loadList() {
  try {
    // Дожидаемся ответа `response` для дальнейшей работы.
    const articles = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    console.log('Записи загружены.');

    // К этому моменту `ajax` запрос
    // уже выполнен, ответ уже получен. 
    renderList(articles);
    console.log('Записи отрисованы.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Все ошибки будут перехватываться здесь.
    console.error('error');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadList();
});
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```